# regex to match the first and only character/symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get `"123"` in `"123" => "abc"`

my regex
`/\".*\"/g`

somehow this won't work, it catched the last `"`

Comment: Your question is quite impossible to understand that what you want. Please clarify.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I'm trying to get "123" in "123" => "abc"

Comment: This is what you said in your question.

Comment: is it very hard to understand I want to match `"123"` from `"123" => "abc"` ?

Comment: So your input string is `"123" => "abc"` and output `123`, isn't it?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna correct.

Comment: @0m3r what if I want to include the `""`?

Comment: @0m3r the left block can be "likethis123.abc" so /d won't work for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because changing the requirements after asking the question is ridiculous.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/C70DL9/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something such as this might work:

```
var pat = "(\\\".*\\\")\\s=>.*" ;
var rex = new RegExp( pat, "gim" ) ;
var rep = "$1" ;
var res = txt.replace( rex, rep ) ;
console.log( res ) ;
```

**Output**:

```
"123"
```

The source string would be `var txt` ...

Comment: didn't work well if my source is like this, https://pastebin.com/abwRUC3J not consistent.

Comment: @JessieAnderson: You should've posted that information to begin with... Anyway changing `\\s` to `\\s*` should allow it to work.

Comment: but it also did not excluded these `<?php

return array(` characters? I want to loop through the length of the left block

Comment: You should've included it in your question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

use the following regex and get the first match :

`\".*?\"`

> ***?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed

Example : https://regex101.com/r/yBFSEO/1/

Note : the first match will return the left hand side of the match string.

Comment: this won't work if the the target is `"123"=>"abc something else"`

Answer (score 0):

*Try* ***`.*?(\"\d{3}\")`***

***https://regex101.com/r/C70DL9/3***

---

> [image]

---

[image]

---

*Or you could*

***`.*?(\"\d{3}\")?`*** and substitution ***`$1`***

[image]

Comment: For `"1234" => "right block"` ,`"1234"` should be selected too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

^\".*?\"

You need to assert the beginning of the line with ^.  Then add in a lazy quantifier

Comment: the problem in your comment now is that the quoted part are no longer beginning on the far left hand side, plus the quoted part is different; there is a period in there.  So now, you will need this: \".*\.\w+\"